# proc sql sum doesn't add up correctly

Tags: sql, sum, sas

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  Date1           Date2       Paid Amount
A               1/25/2012   -168.48
A               1/25/2012   -59.44
A               1/25/2012   -13.18
A               1/25/2012   -8.02
A               1/25/2012   8.02
A               1/25/2012   13.18
A               1/25/2012   59.44
A               1/25/2012   168.48
A   12/28/2011  1/25/2012   50.00
A   12/28/2011  1/25/2012   61.00


Proc sql;
Create table SUM as
Select id, date1, date2, sum(paid_amount) as paid_amount
From SUM_0
Group by id, date1, date2;
```

I get something like this:

```
ID Date1     Date2     paid_amount
A            1/25/2012 4.547474E-13
A 12/28/2011 1/25/2012 111.00
```

Just by eyeballing, it's obvious that the sum of the paid_amount for the blank date1, but 1/25/2012 date2 should be 0.  For some reason for this and other similar setups, I get various sums with E-13 values.

Comment: Looks like a floating point issue. Is `paid_amount` a currency or decimal column?

Comment: It's a numeric with no specificed format or informat, with length 8.

Comment: you output for second row should be 111, not 110.00..  you can check here, its working fine  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a397/1........let us know, what is your table structure

Comment: That's a typo, my bad.  Fixed.

Comment: That sounds like an 8-byte double to me. Where did you find that info and what system are you on?

Comment: The data is confidential patient info pulled using SQL Developer from a data warehouse (I think).  I am on Windows 7 and using SAS 9.4.

Comment: SAS does use 8 byte doubles indeed (by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, this is a floating point issue.  Just like:

```
2/3 - 1/3 - 1/3 = 0
```

but

```
.6667 - .3333 - .3333 > 0
```

Floating point numbers are inherently imprecise.

In `SAS`, you can deal with this a few different ways.  The easiest two:

- Round.  `round(sum(...),0.01)` will round it to the nearest 0.01, and you can round to the nearest 0.000001 if you like; typically `E-12` is where you start seeing floating point precision issues creep in, so any number of zeroes less than 10 or so will do.
- Fuzz.  `Fuzz(...)` automatically rounds numbers close to an integer to that integer.  It doesn't round *otherwise*, just things close to a real integer become one.

For example:

```
data test;
  input ID  $ Date1 :mmddyy10. Date2 :mmddyy10. Amount;
  datalines;
A      .         1/25/2012   -168.48
A      .         1/25/2012   -59.44
A      .         1/25/2012   -13.18
A      .         1/25/2012   -8.02
A      .         1/25/2012   8.02
A      .         1/25/2012   13.18
A      .         1/25/2012   59.44
A      .         1/25/2012   168.48
A   12/28/2011  1/25/2012   50.00
A   12/28/2011  1/25/2012   61.00
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
  select id, date1, date2, round(sum(amount),.01)
    from test
    group by 1,2,3;
quit;
```

Comment: My impression is that the amount values are currency values stored in floating point. Does `round()` convert them to a new type? If not then I think there's some potential for errors to accumulate. Although I acknowledge it would take a very long list of transactions for the error to move up into the pennies, is this worth considering?

Comment: SAS has no other types: just floating point (8 byte by default, as few as 3 if desired) and character.  The problem is that just two operations can end up with something that is no longer equal to exactly zero, which is an issue if you use `if x=0` or similar in your code.

Comment: I understand why rounding "fixes" this particular when the sum should be zero. I was just trying to address the broader issue with using floats where a decimals type is intended.

Comment: Since SAS doesn't have a non-double numeric type, I don't think I understand what you're trying to get at (unless you aren't understanding that?)

Comment: I do. Though there's still a tiny potential for error it's probably not worth the trouble to worry about.

Comment: I ended up using proc summary in SAS and for some reason, it summed up to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a cast like `numeric(10, 2)` inside the `sum()`.

```
sum(cast(paid_amount as decimal(10, 2)))
```

Comment: Errr I'm pretty new at sql, can you explain/elaborate?  Thanks.

Comment: `PROC SQL` is only an implementation of SQL in SAS, and doesn't support the `CAST` function

Comment: Well there must be some equivalent to convert to a decimal/numeric/currency type. They key is to do it prior to summing.

Comment: There is no numeric type other than Double in Base SAS.  The new `DS2` language has some additional types, but most users wouldn't be familiar with that.